# How to edit this mySQL query to return result when a condition is met or a row is not found?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the `data` table and it is like this:

```
id ---- user ---- status
1 ----- abc ----- idle
2 ----- def ----- received
```

that I use the following to get the result

```
WHERE status ='idle' AND user='abc'
```

The above is my try to return the result of the query if `status = idle' for`abc`

However, what I really is to get the result for `abc` even if it does not exist in the `data` table and I tried this

```
 WHERE (status ='idle' or not exists(select * from data where user='2NnG1zvogogH' limit 1)  ) AND user='abc'
```

without luck.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what result you're trying to get? I'm having trouble understanding. Maybe an example would be helpful.

Comment: If there's no `user=abc`, you want to return *all* other rows?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: I still don't understand. You say you want to get the result for abc even if it doesn't exist, but then you show the result for def, not abc.

Comment: @Barmar yes I want to return all other rows

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
WHERE (status = 'idle' and user = 'abc')
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM data WHERE user = 'abc')
```

There's no need for `LIMIT 1` when a subquery is used with `EXISTS`, the database knows that it only has to match a single row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT id, user, status FROM data WHERE status = 'idle'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 0 id, IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM data WHERE user = 'abc') = 0, 'abc', NULL) user, 'status' status
    ) tmp
    WHERE user= 'abc'
) tmp2 ORDER BY id
```

`SELECT id, user, status FROM data WHERE status = 'idle'` will return all the results in the table that meet this criteria. That one is obvious enough.

`SELECT 0 id, IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM data WHERE user = 'abc') = 0, 'abc', NULL) user, 'status' status` will always return one line. The only difference will be if `user = 'abc'` or if `user = NULL`. `user` will return `'abc'` if there is no `user = 'abc'` in the database.

`SELECT * FROM (...) tmp WHERE user= 'abc'` just filters the results from the above query so that if the row is `user = NULL` then it is not included in the rest of the results.

All of this is then ordered in the outermost query.

Comment: This will always include the line that you are looking for with `user = 'abc'` if it is in the database or not and will only include it once (assuming only 1 line in the database with user = abc)

Comment: Edited answer to include an explanation as requested.